# Haskell: Lists and foldl

Tags: list, haskell, fold

I have a series of numbers: 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15,...
Basically, you add 1, then you add 2, then add 3, etc.

I have to make a function where I return this series of numbers in a list up to a given number, n. I want to use foldl.

so, series 5 should return [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]

Here is what I have so far:

```
eachElem n = foldl (+) 0 [0..n]

series n = [x | x <- [(eachElem 0), (eachElem 1)..(eachElem n)]]
```

Basically, I figured that each element in the list was a foldl operation, and so I made a separate helper function (eachElem) to accomplish this.

However, it is returning a list much larger than what I want.

Eg. series 3 => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] when it should really return [0,1,3,6]

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Is this homework? If so it should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: no it [should not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: No homwework tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Mog & Jonke. I missed the memo.

Comment: Should this be done only use foldl/scanl? List comprehension will handle this easily since [x*(x-1)/2 | x <- [1..n]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are so adamant of using `foldl` you can do something like

```
series n  = reverse $ foldl f [0] [1..n]
    where f xs@(x:_) y = x+y:xs
```

In ghci

```
> series 5
[0,1,3,6,10,15]
```

But problem with `foldl` is you can not create infinite series.

You can have infinite series like

```
series = 0:zipWith (+) series [1..]
```

Then you can do something like

```
> take (5+1) series
[0,1,3,6,10,15]
```

I have not tried but you might also use `unfoldr` or similar concept to build your list.

Comment: ``unfoldr (\k -> Just (k*(k+1) `quot` 2, k+1)) 0``

Answer (score 7):

[`scanl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:scanl) is better suited to what you're doing.

Its type is `scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]` -- its type signature is the same as `foldl`'s, but it returns a list of incremental values, instead of just the final result.

I'll leave the rest as an exercise for you, since this seems like homework. Good luck!

Comment: If I have to use foldl, is there a way that I can force it to evaluate the "eachElem n"s in the list before making the list? I think this is where my problem lies... I would assume that in an imperative language, this approach would work. But I've learned that Haskell does "Lazy evaluation"

Comment: Having more laziness than necessary can only affect resource usage, it cannot lead to different results than with forcing. Evaluation forcing is possible, but it isn't necessary in your case.

Answer (score 1):

scanl is the best here, but if you have to use fold try this

```
testso :: Integral a => a -> [a]
testso n = reverse $ foldl (\acc x -> head acc + x:acc ) [0] [1,2..n]
```

gives output as testso 10 [0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55].

Answer (score 0):

When you write [a,b..c], a is the first element, c is the last element and b is the step, it's the interval between every element in the list and if you omit it, it will be defaulted to 1.

So let's have a look at your code, you do:

```
  [x | x <- [(eachElem 0), (eachElem 1)..(eachElem n)]]
```

- In your list comprehension, x will first take the value (eachElem 0) = 0
- Then the next element will be (eachElem 0) + (eachElem 1) = 1
- Then the ith elent will be (eachElem 0) + i*(eachElem 1 - eachElem 0) as long as the value is <= (eachElem n)

Hence your result: [0,1..(eachElem n)] which produces [0,1,2,3... and clearly isn't what you expected.

As suggested by amindfv, you should have a look at scanl.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `series` is wrong.

`[(eachElem 0), (eachElem 1)..(eachElem n)]` becomes `[0, 1, eachElem n]` which is actually every number up to `eachElem n`.

You actually want to do this:

```
series n = [eachElem x | x <- [0..n]]
```

Answer (score 0):

the definition

```
series n = [ x | x <- [(eachElem 0)..(eachElem n)]]
```

is wrong!

For instance:

because of

```
eachElem 0 -> 0
eachElem 3 -> 6
```

series 3 evaluates to

```
series 3 -> [(eachElem 0)..(eachElem 3)] -> [0..6] -> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

You need something like that

```
series' n = [ eachElem x | x <- [0..n]]
```

tests:

```
> let series' n = [ eachElem x | x <- [0..n]]
> let series n = [ x | x <- [(eachElem 0)..(eachElem n)]]

> series' 3
> [0,1,3,6]

> series 3
> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

> eachElem 0
> 0

> eachElem 3
> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat :-)

```
series x = foldl (\xs n -> (n*(n+1) `div` 2):xs) [] [x,(x-1)..0]
```